# Do the Spring Tools in the VsCode version have the same features as the Eclipse version?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spring-tools-4

I tried to find videos or texts explaining the difference, but I didn't find anything to convince me. I'm just getting started and I want to specialize in an IDE only, if possible. I'm studying JScript (vue) frameworks and I'm already using VSCode for that.

P.S .: forgiveness for my English. I know it's terrible

Tanks

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Tools 4 offerings differ indeed slightly between the different IDEs. In case you are already using Visual Studio Code, I would recommend to stay with that IDE, add the Java Extension Pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and the Spring Extension Pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack) to it, and go from there.

You can take a look at the readme of those extensions to see which features are included. The majority of the Spring specific tooling is included across the different IDES.

One bigger difference is the Spring Boot dashboard, which includes a bunch of features when used in Eclipse, but a lot less in the Visual Studio Code environment. That is probably the most noticeable difference.

In the end, this is more a matter of which IDE you prefer in general and go from there. And in case you are missing something specific, let us know. Your feedback and enhancement requests would be more than welcome.